# how to sum in django model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two models here one is contains subject info and another one course info, i want to sum how many credits(total) have in this course,to show in template. i have tried but didn't work.
thank you so much

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subject', related_name='subject_list', blank=True)

def tota_credit(self):
    total = 0
    for cred in self.subject_set.all():
        total += cred.credit
    return total  # doesn't work :(


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

another model

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   code = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
   credit = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
class Course_detail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'queryset'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    self.profile = Student.objects.all()
  
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile'] = self.profile
    return context
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: just need total credits of the course for example: a course contains five subjects so there will be 5 different credits no, like 2 , 3 , 5, i want total = 10, how do i able to have that sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to perform these calculations yourself. You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Course_detail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_detail.html'
    queryset = Course.objects.annotate(
        total_credit=Sum('subject__credit')
    )
    context_object_name = 'queryset'

    # …
```

Then you can render this with:

```
{{ queryset }}: {{ queryset.total_credit }}
```

Comment: its showing error TypeError at /student/department/program/course/details/3/
'Course' object is not iterable, why? i think your ans should work, but i am not getting it :(

Comment: @Rafikhan: because it is a `DetailView`, so `queryset` is not queryset, but a `Course` object. You thus render it with `{{ queryset }}: {{ queryset.total_credit }}`. Although the value for the `context_object_name` is misleading.

Comment: what should i do now ? how i do i fix that?, thanks for your help appreciate

Comment: @Rafikhan: you render the single object with `{{ queryset }}: {{ queryset.total_credit }}`, so no `{% for ... %}` loops.

Comment: love you Sir :) i have no words how, much i'm appreciate.

Comment: sir sorry to bother you, now i'm getting single course total. but is it possible to have all course credit total by that user? because he/she could have more than one course. for example one course total 12 another one 8 ...so total = 20.

Comment: @Rafikhan: can you please ask a new question, and include how the courses relate to the users?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389453/how-to-calculate-sum-in-django-models sir i have just post the question please visit that...

Answer (score 1):

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

...
def tota_credit(self):
  return self.subject_set.aggregate(Sum('credit'))['credit_sum']
```