# How to calculate sum in django models/views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make result app for student, there are two models one is for subject one for course, every course have more than one subject with subject credit, so I want to sum all subject credits depends on the course, now I'm getting single course's total subject credit, but is it possible to have all course's subjects credit total? because he/she could have more than one course. for example one course's subject total credit = 12 another one credit = 8 .......so total = 20 credits please see the images [image: courses with subject and showing total credits no by the student]  [image: want your suggestion for design this model in django] and what will be better approach for second image model design

*models.py*

```
    class Subject(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(
                      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       code = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
       credit = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
       files = models.FileField(upload_to='course/materials/', blank=True)
       status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=Subject_Status, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        

    class Meta:
        db_table = ''
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Subject'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subjects'


    class Course(models.Model):
         user = models.ForeignKey(
              settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
         name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
         prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20)
         code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
         subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subject', related_name='subject_list', blank=True)

         faield = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='failed_subject_status', blank=True)
         passed = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='passed_subject_status', blank=True)
         nerver = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='never_subject_status', blank=True)
         current = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='curent_subject_status', blank=True)
    
         program = models.ForeignKey('Program', related_name='program_course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    blank=True, null=True)
```

*views.py*

```
    class Program_structure(generic.View):

        def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            profile = Student.objects.all()
            program_structure = Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            credit = 
              Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(total_credit=Sum('subject__credit'))

           context = {
            'test':program_structure,
            'credit':credit,         #this is giving single course total 
            'profile':profile,

           }
            return render(self.request, 'test.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up the total `credit`s of the `Subject`s of the `Course`s of the `request.user` with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_credit = request.user.course_set.aggregate(
    total_credit=Sum('subject__credit')
)['total_credit'] or 0
```

for example:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Program_structure(generic.View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = Student.objects.all()
        program_structure = Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        credit = 
          Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(total_credit=Sum('subject__credit'))
        total_credit = request.user.course_set.aggregate(
            total_credit=Sum('subject__credit')
        )['total_credit'] or 0

       context = {
           'test':program_structure,
           'credit':credit,         #this is giving single course total 
           'profile':profile,
           'total_credit' : total_credit
       }
       return render(self.request, 'test.html', context)
```

and then render it in the template with:

```
{{ total_credit }}
```

Comment: how do i apply that in my tempates?

Comment: @Rafikhan: you can pass the total credit through the context in your template. So you calculate this in the `get` method, add the result to the `context`, and render the context variable.

Comment: oh, i am so stuck, can you consider please add this in your ans please :)

Comment: course = Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).aggregate(total_credit=Sum('subject__credit'))   if i loop through how can get the total

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXL08.png sir what would be better approach for design this model like the this image? is my course model enough for that? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of annotate you can use the aggregate.

```
credit = Course.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).aggregate(total_credit=Sum('subject__credit'))
```